# How to remove the last CR char with `cut`

Tags: linux, cut, carriage-return

I would like to get a portion of a string using `cut`. Here a dummy example:

```
$ echo "foobar" | cut -c1-3 | hexdump -C
00000000  66 6f 6f 0a                                       |foo.|
00000004
```

Notice the `\n` char added at the end.

In that case there is no point to use `cut` to remove the last char as follow:

```
echo "foobar" | cut -c1-3 | rev | cut -c 1- | rev
```

I will still get this extra and unwanted char and I would like to avoid using an extra command such as:

```
shasum file | cut -c1-16 | perl -pe chomp
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\n` is added by `echo`. Instead, use `printf`:

```
$ echo "foobar" | od -c
0000000   f   o   o   b   a   r  \n
0000007
$ printf "foobar" | od -c
0000000   f   o   o   b   a   r
0000006
```

It is funny that `cut` itself also adds a new line:

```
$ printf "foobar" | cut -b1-3 | od -c
0000000   f   o   o  \n
0000004
```

So the solution seems using `printf` to its output:

```
$ printf "%s" $(cut -b1-3  <<< "foobar") | od -c
0000000   f   o   o
0000003
```