# Trailing new line after piping to a command: is there any standard?

Tags: bash, unix, posix, gnu

Answering [How to remove the last CR char with `cut`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36621909/1983854) I found out that some programs do add a trailing new line to the end of a string, while others don't:

Say we have the string `foobar` and print it with `printf` so that we don't get an extra new line:

```
$ printf "foobar" | od -c
0000000   f   o   o   b   a   r
0000006
```

Or with `echo -n`:

```
$ echo -n "foobar" | od -c
0000000   f   o   o   b   a   r
0000006
```

(`echo`'s default behaviour is to return the output followed by a newline, so `echo "foobar"` returns `f   o   o   b   a   r  \n`).

Neither `sed` nor `cat` do add any extra character:

```
$ printf "foobar" | sed 's/./&/g' | od -c
0000000   f   o   o   b   a   r
0000006
$ printf "foobar" | cat - | od -c
0000000   f   o   o   b   a   r
0000006
```

Whereas both `awk` and `cut` do. Also `xargs` and `paste` add this trailing new line:

```
$ printf "foobar" | cut -b1- | od -c
0000000   f   o   o   b   a   r  \n
0000007
$ printf "foobar" | awk '1' | od -c
0000000   f   o   o   b   a   r  \n
0000007
$ printf "foobar" | xargs | od -c
0000000   f   o   o   b   a   r  \n
0000007
$ printf "foobar" | paste | od -c
0000000   f   o   o   b   a   r  \n
0000007
```

So I was wondering: why is this different behaviour? Is there anything POSIX suggests about this?

Note I am running all of this in my Bash 4.3.11 and the rest is:

- GNU Awk 4.0.1
- sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
- cat (GNU coreutils) 8.21
- cut (GNU coreutils) 8.21
- xargs (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
- paste (GNU coreutils) 8.21

Comment: I think POSIX just insists that anything "textual" has to have a final newline, whereas applications which are not exclusively text tools have some wiggle room.  It's hard to see how `sed` would differ from Awk in this regard but maybe it's just an oversight; also, `sed` has more random implementations which probably complicated the standardization process in the first place, and vendors may have had reasons to prioritize backwards compatibility over strict compliance in more cases.

Comment: Regarding `awk`. The default behaviour for true without a block is `print`. Which as stated in the manual prints the current line and the current `ORS`. If you used printf instead or changed the ORS then you get like for like output. `Sed` OTOH just prints exactly what is in the buffer, if it has a newline it is printed, if not then it's not.

Comment: @123 good point. I did `printf "foobar" | awk -v ORS= '1' | od -c` and it indeed just returns `foobar` without any trailing new line. So regarding `sed`, it seems like this and `cat` have the same behaviour since they are not "touching" the stream. Still curious, though, whether there is some kind of standard expected behaviour.

Comment: I don't think there is as all the commands you have shown have different purposes and so process the data differently. Xargs for example has a default to just echo the data passed to it if no option is chosen, it isn't meant to output text though, you are supposed to supply it with a command, using printf would give like for like. Again with paste, it's purpose is `Write lines consisting of the sequentially corresponding lines from each FILE`, so obviously it has to add it's own newlines.

Comment: The `awk` behaviour here is well-known, I think - it's one way to add a trailing newline to files which don't have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I was wondering: why is this different behaviour? Is there anything POSIX suggests about this?

Some commands (like for example `printf`) are simple interface to the `libc` library calls (e.g. `printf()`) which don't add `\n` automatically. Most *NIX text processing commands would add a `\n` on the end of the last line.

From the [Definitions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html) of POSIXv7, a textual line has to have a `newline` on the end:

> > 3.206 Line
>
> A sequence of zero or more non- `<newline>` characters plus a terminating  character.

If the `newline` is missing, it becomes this:

> > 3.195 Incomplete Line
>
> A sequence of one or more non- `<newline>` characters at the end of the file.

The general idea is that text file can be treated as a list of records, where every record is terminated by `\n`. In other words, `\n` is not something between lines - it is the part of the line. See for example the [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) function: the `\n` is always included and serves to identify the case whether the text line was read completely or not. If the last line is missing the `\n`, then one has to do more checks to read the file correctly.

In general, as long as your text files are created on *NIX by *NIX programs/scripts, it is fine to expect that last line is properly terminated. But many Java applications as well as the Windows applications do not handle that correctly or consistently. Not only they often forget to add the last `\n`, oftentimes they also incorrectly treat the trailing `\n` as an additional empty line.

Comment: Does this mean that some of the programs do use some `libc` library calls whereas others don't, and that's why they behave differently?

Comment: No. The `libc` is only a tool. The new line handling lies in responsibility of the software developer, and some simply forget to add the `'\n'`. On *NIX systems there is a tradition, and convention, for the text files. It is also standardized by the POSIX and developers are advised to adhere to it.

Comment: OK so the expected POSIX behaviour is set, only that people writing these programs may or may not follow it. I wondered if there was any *must* here.

Comment: Standardized behavior is by definition a "must". OTOH, practically speaking, the last `'\n'` is (was?) needed by some buggy application which might miss the last line of a file, if it didn't contain the terminating newline character. Some text tools from *NIX (still seen on the commercial Unix systems!) are like that. Microsoft's assembler (masm) and IDL compilers I crossed in the past had this bug too, and it was even documented as a "feature".