# Why is sed adding a new line to the file and how to prevent it?

Tags: macos, command-line, sed

How can I prevent sed from adding a new line at the end of the file using this command:

```
find . -not -path "./.git/*" -type f -name '*' -exec sed -i '' 's/password1/passworddeleted/g; s/password2/passworddeleted/g;' {} +
```

EDIT: 
To prove my question:

```
mkdir test; cd test; printf "no new lines" > no-new-line.txt; cat -e no-new-line.txt; find . -not -path "./.git/*" -type f -name '*' -exec sed -i '' 's/password1/passworddeleted/g; s/password2/passworddeleted/g;' {} +; cat -e no-new-line.txt;
```

Will output `no new linesno new lines$`. `cat -e` displays non-printing characters on mac.

Comment: This is not adding any new line to me. What OS are you running this on? Try providing a [mcve] as well.

Comment: I added an example. Thanks for pointing it to me.

Comment: Interesting. In CentOS I do not get any new line. Funny thing I asked something similar about new lines being or not being added by programs, and `sed` apparently does not. See it in [Trailing new line after piping to a command: is there any standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36641445/1983854).

Comment: A file without a terminating newline is not a text file and so you should not expect a text-processing tool like sed or awk or grep or... to be able to handle it in any particular way. See [why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline).

Comment: @EdMorton A text file may have 0 lines, hence can not be defined in terms of newline. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_397.

Comment: @Kenavoz we're getting bit lawer-y now but fine `s/A file/A non-empty file/` or however you feel it should be stated.

Comment: @EdMorton Interesting link anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` *always* ends its output by a newline character and you cannot force it to do otherwise.

From [POSIX man sed](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/sed/):

> Whenever the pattern space is written to standard output or a named file, sed shall immediately follow it with a newline.

As an alternative, you can use something else than `sed` or strip the last character of `sed`'s output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, or combine with pipe:

```
truncate -s -1 <file>
```

(this remove the last byte of the file )