# Why does wc count one extra character in my file?

Tags: linux, bash, wc

1.) I am using Debian 8.4 on a virtual box and as I ran the command `wc sample.txt` to sample.txt containing:

```
Hello
```

The output to the command was

```
1 1 6 sample.txt
```

Is the extra character EOF? If it is then how come when I ran the same command for an empty file the output was..

```
0 0 0 sample.txt
```

Comment: Also, cross-site duplicates: http://serverfault.com/questions/287370/why-wc-c-always-count-1-more-character http://superuser.com/questions/525902/linux-shell-wc-c-count-characters-1 http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85268/why-do-i-get-one-more-number-of-bytes-reported-in-a-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a trailing new line and this is what `wc` reports.

See for example if we create a file with `printf`:

```
$ printf "hello" > a
$ cat a | hexdump -c
0000000   h   e   l   l   o
0000005
$ wc a
0 1 5 a
```

However, if we write with something like `echo`, a trailing new line is appended:

```
$ echo "hello" > a
$ cat a | hexdump -c
0000000   h   e   l   l   o  \n
0000006
$ wc a
1 1 6 a
```

Comment: If it was a newline character, wouldnt wc output 2 lines instead of 1?

Comment: No, `\n` is the last character in the first line.

Comment: @Patrick and, in fact, `wc` counts how many new lines the file contains. That's why my first example shows `0` in the first column.

Comment: I ran the code above and it is indeed a newline character. I didnt expect a newline to be added even when I had not inputted one. Thanks!

Comment: @Patrick it is very common to have newlines appended to the end of streams. This also surprised me, so it triggered me ask [Trailing new line after piping to a command: is there any standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36641445/1983854).

Comment: Interesting question. I will dig into it once I am more familiar with the shell since I am still a beginner and these things tend to become quite overwhelming.

Comment: You can see the exact contents of your file using `od`. e.g. `od -c sample.txt`.